# Smartart hierarchy nodes - can only fill in one textframe of each node

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build an organization chart automatically from data in Excel using Excel VBA. It works out fine, however, I would like to have both textframes filled in. In the big textframe I would like to have filled in the description of the department, and in the smaller textframe I would have like to add the department code.

[smartart hierarchy layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9rUl.png)

[image: smartart hierarchy layout]

I can't find the code to access the smaller textframe.

```
Do While Source.Cells(Line, 1) <> ""
    If Source.Cells(Line, 3) = PID Then
        Set ParNode = QNode
        If Source.Cells(Line, 4) = 1 Then
        Set QNode = QNode.AddNode(msoSmartArtNodeDefault, msoSmartArtNodeTypeAssistant)
        Else: Set QNode = QNode.AddNode(msoSmartArtNodeBelow)
        End If
        QNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Cells(Line, 6)
        'here something needs to be added !!!

        CurPid = Source.Cells(Line, 2)
        If Not Found Then Found = True 'something was find


        'Source.Rows(Line).Delete
        'Line = Line + 1
        Call AddChildNodes(QNode, Source, CurPid)
        Debug.Print ("CurPid" & CurPid)
        Debug.Print ("line" & Line)
        Set QNode = ParNode
    'ElseIf Found Then    'it's sorted,so nothing else can be found
     '   Exit Do
    'Else

    End If
    Line = Line + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Have you tried to record a macro while doing it manually?

Comment: @DirkReichel: Have you? And looked at the result?

Comment: @teylyn you are right... recording won't help... but there are other tools working perfectly :)

Comment: @DirkReichel what do you mean with other tools?

Comment: See the picture in my answer :)

Comment: @user3170975 pls tell me if my answer is correct or not...

Answer (score 2):

the upper line (where your CEO-text is)

```
                               QNode.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
***.SmartArt.AllNodes(...).Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
```

the lower line where your smartart is empty:

```
***.SmartArt.AllNodes(...).Shapes(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
```

you need to check if `QNode.Shapes(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text` works. if not, you may need to use `.parent`

[image: source]